# Encontrar valores duplicados num array

Tags: php

Tenho um `foreach` e ele tem resultados iguais, quero que quando ele tiver o mesmo resultado ele faça um `echo`

Exemplo do código:

```
$courses = array('teste', 'teste2', 'teste3', 'teste');
foreach ($courses as $key => $course) {
     if ($course == $course) {
           echo $course;
     }
}
```

Falta no exemplo a segunda variavel de comparação, no exemplo usei a mesma `$course->fullname` nos 2 lugares do if

**EDIT: preciso que o if identifique os 2 valores 'teste' e dê um  `echo`**

Comment: Edite seu código conforme está fazendo mesmo, por favor.

Comment: Essa segunda variável tem seu valor alterado? é um foreach dentro de outro?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e monte um exemplo mais próximo do código real se não puder mostra ele. Dá até pra sugerir um `array_intersect()` ou afim.

Comment: montei outro exemplo... @rray

Comment: O objetivo é encontrar valores iguais num array?

Comment: sim!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6):

Na verdade você não precisa de um `foreach` para identificar os valores duplicados:

```
$courses = array('teste', 'teste2', 'teste3', 'teste');
function getDuplicates( $array ) {
    return array_unique( array_diff_assoc( $array, array_unique( $array ) ) );
}

$duplicates = getDuplicates($courses);

print_r($duplicates);
```

**Obs:** Agora é só fazer um `foreach` nas duplicatas e dar echo em tudo.

[**IDEONE de exemplo**](http://ideone.com/GPk2sC)

Answer (score 3):

Também é possível identificar os elementos repetidos com a função `array_count_values()` que retorna um array, onde as chaves são os elementos e os valores o número de ocorrências, com isso, basta um foreach e um if perguntando é maior que um? se sim é repetido.

```
$courses = array('2015', 'teste', 'teste2', 'wow', 'teste3', 'teste', 'wow');
$arr = array_count_values($courses);

foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($value > 1){
        echo 'valor repetido: '. $key .'<br>';
    }
}
```