# Contar quantas vezes uma string aparece em um Objeto

Tags: php

Tenho um Objeto retornado da API do Facebook e gostaria de "Contar" as reações de um post.

Tenho este trecho do código:

```
// Descodificando o JSON
    $objeto  = json_decode($userNode['reactions']);

// Percorrendo dados
    foreach( $objeto as $tipo )
    {
        echo $tipo->type."<br />";
    }
```

**PS: `var_dump($objeto);`**

```
array (size=6)
 0 => 
object(stdClass)[115]
  public 'id' => string '753855038121014' (length=15)
  public 'name' => string 'Ivone Kodama' (length=12)
  public 'type' => string 'LIKE' (length=4)
1 => 
object(stdClass)[113]
  public 'id' => string '392780707772557' (length=15)
  public 'name' => string 'Eunice Garcez' (length=13)
  public 'type' => string 'LIKE' (length=4)
2 => 
object(stdClass)[114]
  public 'id' => string '1355251021162174' (length=16)
  public 'name' => string 'Gih Andrea Anastacio De Carvalho Baracat' (length=40)
  public 'type' => string 'SAD' (length=3)
3 => 
object(stdClass)[54]
  public 'id' => string '408046949554084' (length=15)
  public 'name' => string 'Terezinha Piassa' (length=16)
  public 'type' => string 'LIKE' (length=4)
4 => 
object(stdClass)[51]
  public 'id' => string '194465404377613' (length=15)
  public 'name' => string 'Sueli Aparecida' (length=15)
  public 'type' => string 'LIKE' (length=4)
```

Me retorna o seguinte:

`WOW
 WOW
 LIKE
 LIKE
 HAHA
 WOW
 LIKE
 LIKE
 SAD
 LIKE
 LIKE
 HAHA`

Etc...Como posso "saber" quantas vezes se repete a palavra *LIKE* por exemplo ?

Comment: Se é um array ( `$objeto->type`)  pode fazer assim: [Encontrar valores duplicados num array](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/162741/91)

Comment: @rray não entendi, poderia ser um pouco mais claro? Obrigado

Comment: Pode pegar o array que tem esses valores e usar a função `array_count_values()` ela vai retornar o número de vezes que apareceu as palavras. Só precisa saber exatamente qual é a chave do array/objeto a aplicar.

Comment: @rray olhe a edição por favor.

Comment: @Miguel considere apenas a print do lado esquerdo: https://imageshack.us/i/pmmeNF0Gp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se não tem um motivo especial para trabalhar com objetos simplique retornando um array no `json_decode()`. Com isso pode extrair os valores da chave `type` (`array_column()` php5.5) e aplicar o `array_count_values()` direto.

Exemplo do json:

```
$arr = array(
         array('id' => '753855038121014', 'type' => 'LIKE'),
         array('id' => '392780707772557', 'type' => 'LIKE'),
         array('id' => '1355251021162174', 'type' => 'SAD'),
         array('id' => '408046949554084', 'type' => 'LIKE'),
         array('id' => '194465404377613', 'type' => 'LIKE')
       );
```

PHP >= 5.5

```
$arr  = json_decode($userNode['reactions'], true);
$termos = array_count_values(array_column($arr, 'type'));
echo $termos['LIKE'];
```

PHP < 5.5

```
$arr  = json_decode($userNode['reactions'], true);
$termos = array_map(function($item){ return $item['type']; }, $arr);
$termos = array_count_values($termos);
echo $termos['LIKE'];
```

Pode montar um resumo da seguinte forma:

```
foreach($termos as $key => $value){
    $qtd = $value > 1 ? 'vezes' : 'vez';
    printf("%s: %s %s. <br>", $key, $value, $qtd);
}
echo 'TOTAL: '. array_sum($termos);
```

Saida:

```
LIKE: 4 vezes.
SAD: 1 vez.
TOTAL: 5
```

Comment: segue a saída, como posso somar todos valores?

Comment: @LucasBicalleto No segundo código faltou o `array_count_values()`

Comment: estou usando o primeiro código, como posso contar todos os valores igual retornados na tua resposta ?

Comment: @LucasBicalleto você colocou esse código dentro do foreach? ele não deve repetir os valores.

Comment: sim pois eu to pegando todos os posts, aí preciso colocar dentro do Foreach.

Comment: terei que abrir outra issue ??

Comment: @LucasBicalleto precisa jogar o código da resposta depois do foreach, qualquer coisa coloca o código q vc tem no pastebin e passa o link.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/pXT57xeF

Comment: @LucasBicalleto acho que é melhor criar outra pergunta.

Comment: entendi, pode me auxiliar para formalizar a pergunta?

Comment: @LucasBicalleto eu não exatamente o que vc quer contar? é reações por post? contar todas totalizadas independente do post?

Answer (score 2):

Poderás usar a [esta função](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) do php

exemplo:

```
$array = ['a','b','c','b'];
$arrayCount = array_count_values(array_map('strtolower', $array));
$arrayCountB = $arrayCount['b']; // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o reduce para reduzir o seu array a um array contendo apenas o item e a quantidade;

```
$reduce = array_reduce($objeto,function($carry, $item){
    if(empty($carry[$item->type])) $carry[$item->type] = 1;
    else $carry[$item->type]++;
    return $carry;
},[]);

echo json_encode($reduce); //{"LIKE":4,"SAD":1}
```

Comment: deu certo: sem querer pedir muito, pode me ajudar a "juntar" tudo ? pois ta assim **{"LIKE":3,"ANGRY":1}{"LIKE":1}{"LIKE":7,"SAD":2}{"LIKE":12,"ANGRY":1,"HAHA":3,"WOW":6,"SAD":1}{"LIKE":18,"WOW":1}{"LIKE":24,"HAHA":1}{"LIKE":1}{"LIKE":20,"HAHA":1,"SAD":1,"LOVE":3}{"LIKE":5}{"LIKE":20,"SAD":1,"LOVE":2,"ANGRY":1,"WOW":1}{"LIKE":24,"LOVE":1}{"LIKE":1}{"LIKE":24,"WOW":1}{"LIKE":10}{"LIKE":2}{"LIKE":18,"SAD":2,"WOW":1,"ANGRY":4}{"HAHA":15,"WOW":1,"LIKE":9}{"LIKE":8}{"LIKE":20,"HAHA":3,"LOVE":2}{"LIKE":24,"LOVE":1}{"LIKE":25}{"LIKE":20,"ANGRY":2,"WOW":2,"SAD":1}**

Comment: Você está executando em um loop e vem vários objetos, dai vc quer juntar todos eles?

Comment: Isso, juntar de maneira que fique mais o menos assim: {"LIKE":100,"ANGRY":20 etc....} Todos em apenas 1

Comment: Nesse caso você pode usar um array_merge para fazer todos os itens de todos os arrays virarem um array só, dai vc pode continuar usando o array_reduce acima , ou agrupar tudo em uma variável , fazendo algo assim

 foreach($reduce as $type => $value){
  if(empty($groupType[$type])) $groupType[$type] = $value;
  else $groupType[$type] += $value;
 }

Onde o $groupType é a variável que vai agrupar os itens,