# Maximo de ocorrências de um item

Tags: php, codeigniter

Preciso percorrer os dados e descobrir o numero máximo de ocorrências de um item. Eu possuo a seguinte estrutura

```
array(5) {
    [0]=>
     object(stdClass)#26 (6) {
      ["num_dia"] => string(1) "5"
      ["num_semana"] => string(2) "46"
      ["descricao"] => string(5) "Teste"
     }
    [1]=>
     object(stdClass)#27 (6) {
      ["num_dia"]=> string(1) "5"
      ["num_semana"]=>string(2) "46"
      ["descricao"]=>string(8) "Testeeee"
   }
    [2]=>
     object(stdClass)#28 (6) {
      ["num_dia"]=>string(1) "6"
      ["num_semana"]=>string(2) "46"
      ["descricao"]=>string(5) "Teste"
   }
    [3]=>
     object(stdClass)#29 (6) {
      ["num_dia"]=>string(1) "6"
      ["num_semana"]=>string(2) "47"
      ["descricao"]=>string(7) "Teste 1"
   }
   [4]=>
     object(stdClass)#30 (6) {
      ["num_dia"]=>string(1) "5"
      ["num_semana"]=>string(2) "48"
      ["descricao"]=>string(7) "Bla bla"
    }
}
```

**Fiz isso no momento.**

```
   $count = 0;
    $ativ_max = [];
    $atual_max = 0;
    $antigo_max = 0;

            for ($i=0; $i < count($ativ_semanal); $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j < count($ativ_semanal[$i]->num_semana); $j++) {
            if ($i == 0|| $ativ_semanal[$i]->num_semana == $ativ_semanal[$i-1]->num_semana) {
                if ($i == 0 || $ativ_semanal[$i]->num_dia == $ativ_semanal[$i-1]->num_dia) {
                    $atual_max++;
                }else{
                    if ($antigo_max < $atual_max) {
                        $antigo_max = $atual_max;
                        if ($i == count($ativ_semanal[$i]->num_semana)) {
                            $ativ_max = array($ativ_semanal[$i]->num_semana => $antigo_max);
                        }
                    }
                    $atual_max = 1;
                }
            }else{
                var_dump($antigo_max);
                $ativ_max = array($ativ_semanal[$i]->num_semana => $antigo_max);
                $atual_max=1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Ele esta criando o array associativo

```
print_r($item); // Array ( [46] => 3 [47] => 1 [48] => 1 )
```

Porém só o primeiro esta certo (`índice 46`), o segundo esta somando `+1` aos `2` do `índice 46`, ele deveria ser **2** e não **3**. Visto que o máximo de itens foi no dia **5**, e foram 2 itens.

Comment: Acredito que ajude => https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194196/91

Comment: Boa tarde @rray, na verdade já havia visto isso, porém não é exatamente o que eu preciso, eu estou trazendo o numero da semana `num_semana` do banco, eu preciso que se numa segunda tem 1 `descricao` e numa sexta tem 5 `descricao` criar um array $arr[num_semana] = 5.

Comment: Preciso contar o máximo de ocorrências do item que houve na semana.

Comment: Se cada dia da semana por exemplo tiver 1 item, o máximo foi 1 e não 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$itens = [];
foreach ($ativ_semanal as $ativ) {
    if (array_key_exists($ativ->num_semana, $itens)) {
        $itens[$ativ->num_semana]++;
    } else {
        $itens[$ativ->num_semana] = 1;
    }
}
```

É isso o que você está tentando fazer? Porque parece é isso que que você quer como saída, mas isso não bate com a sua pergunta. Na sua pergunta você diz que quer contar o número de itens (o que é definido pela descrição), mas na saída você aparentemente não se importa com o tipo, apenas com a quantidade de itens em dada semana.

Comment: Realmente me expressei mal, porém é quase isso, só que no seu exemplo se por acaso tiver 3 itens na semana, 2 na sexta e 1 na quinta, ele vai me retornar 3, mas deveria retornar 2, eu preciso do máximo de itens do dia. Acho que ficou mais claro o que eu estou perguntando

Comment: O retorno deve ser o dia que tiver mais itens, e não a soma dos itens da semana.

Comment: Então por que no seu exemplo você diz quer **$itens[46] = 2**, sendo que nenhum dos dias equivale a 2?

Comment: Equivale, eles são no mesmo dia. num_dia = 1

Comment: Atualizei o array que eu preciso percorrer, agora fica um pouco melhor de ver.

Comment: Meu retorno no momento esta sendo: `Array ( [46] => **3** [47] => 1 [48] => 1 )` e agora é para ser `Array ( [46] => **2** [47] => 1 [48] => 1 )`